# How to choose the secure password pattern?

Tags: password-management, password-policy

I'm currently developing the iOS app, which is related to saving the document in cloud. so my question is, What alphabetic password length took long time to crack by attackers? Also any suggestion for choosing highly secured password pattern are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best pattern is no pattern, passwords should be random.

A better way is to pick 4 random words as seen [here](https://xkcd.com/936/) but you should note that these words should be random, not your favorite color, band, name and the thing that sits at the back of your desk because that is not random. This is easier due to the fact you only have to remember 4 real(ish) things not 8+ abstract characters.

Extra ways you can increase the difficulty is by adding (nor replacing a letter) a number or special character into the middle, preferably middle of a word.

To answer the question within your question, depending on how the password is handled by the system upto 8 characters is able to be found either within precalculated tables (takes almost no time to find) or takes very little time to calculate. So [it is considered](https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/time-to-crack.jpg) that 9+ characters are considered hard to crack, but that is only for random passwords, if it is **one** long word or **one** phrase then it is considered easy to crack no matter how long it is.